# Create EER Model from an existing DB but with the relations done - Workbench

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to import an existing DB to mysqlq Workbench. I can do this. It's works perfectly. However the process just import the tables without relations between them.

How can I import the the db and create the eer model with relations between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relationships are the visual expression of foreign keys. If your DB tables use foreign keys (actually: a storage engine supporting foreign keys) then they are automatically shown in the diagram. It should be clear that this condition is only true for the InnoDB storage engine.

Comment: I am using mariaDB with InnoDB storage engine. There is no relation between tables. how can i show relationship between tables.

Comment: Are there foreign keys defined?

Comment: No, There is not defined foreign key.

Comment: No foreign keys, no fun.